# How can I parse nested description list(dl tag) with Jsoup?

Tags: jsoup

I want to parse nested description list with Jsoup. I can parse flatten dt dd tags with for loop and child elements. But my code doesn't fit with all depths of description list.

```
<dt><span class="chapter"><a href="jls-1.html">1. Introduction</a></span></dt>
               <dd>
                  <dl>
                     <dt><span class="section"><a href="jls-1.html#jls-1.1">1.1. Organization of the Specification</a></span></dt>
                     <dt><span class="section"><a href="jls-1.html#jls-1.2">1.2. Example Programs</a></span></dt>
```

code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < toc.size(); i++) {
    Element child = children.get(i);
//... processing child texts

}
```

When the depth of description list increase, this for loop doesn't work for sub nested child elements. This code works only when the depth of the description list is 1.IS there a technique that can parse for all depths of description lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css selectors. For example like this:

```
for (Element e :  Jsoup.parse(html).select("dd > dl > dt > span > a")){
            System.out.println(e.text());   
}
```

More about selectors here: 
https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax